# Mean of 3 rows in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, mean

I have a matrix of the following setup:

```
d <- read.table(text='Sample     Target    Value
Sample1    A          NA
Sample1    A          2
Sample1    A          3
Sample2    A          1
Sample2    A          2
Sample2    A          3
Sample1    B          1
Sample1    B          2
Sample1    B          3
Sample2    B          NA
Sample2    B          2
Sample2    B          3',  header=TRUE)
```

I would like to take the means of the `Value` column for each data repetition.
So the mean of all rows that have `Sample=Sample1` and `Target=A`, `Sample=Sample2` and `Target=B` and so on and so forth.

The output should be a matrix like this:

```
result <- read.table(text='Sample     Target    Value
Sample1    A          mean
Sample2    A          mean
Sample1    B          mean
Sample2    B          mean' ,  header=TRUE)
```

I tried to solve this with `aggregate()`, but I am unsure how to code it, so it preserves the `Sample` and `Target` columns and disregard the `NA`

Thank you!

Comment: `aggregate(Value ~ Sample + Target, data=d, FUN=mean)`

Comment: `d` and `result` are not an R matrices. They are data frames.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to solve the problem.
I am quite new to R, so I am not so familiar with the differences between dataframes and matrixes.

I run into a problem though:
In my origional code, the NA is in brackets, <NA>
This causes all results to be NA
Any idea why this is?

Comment: Edit:
What I call a matrix and asked for a solution as a dataframe seems to be a list
as `typeof(x)` returns `list`

Answer (score 2):

I think `aggregate` is ok in this case. Try:

```
aggregate(d$Value, list(d$Sample, d$Target), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  Group.1 Group.2   x
1 Sample1       A 2.5
2 Sample2       A 2.0
3 Sample1       B 2.0
4 Sample2       B 2.5
```